# Clean database with Flyway after each test class

Tags: spring, junit5, flyway

we are in situation where we cannot simple rollback data after test, so we decide to use Flyway java API like this:

```
 @Autowired
 protected Flyway flyway;

 @AfterEach
 public void restoreDatabase() {
     flyway.clean();
     flyway.migrate();
 }
```

Is possible execute clean and migrate after each test class instead of test method? I need call this in `@AfterAll` annotated static method, but this type of methods have to be static so I cannot use autowired component `Flyway`. Can you advice me any workaround? Thank you.

Comment: I never tried it but you can use setter injection and write to a static field which you then access in the after-all method. Here’s an example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-static-field

Comment: What do you mean with "you cannot rollback"? There is this org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback annotation, which will on class level freshly start the server (with all migrations). Combined with a in memory DB (like H2) you should be able to achieve what you want

Comment: @Vetemi for instance we have nested transactions inside one bigger once, and after because of nested transactions data are not rollbacked

Answer (score 2):

The following solution may help you.

Besides the @Rollback annotation there is also the possibility to mark a class (or method) as "dirty" with the annotation `org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext`. This will provide the test cases a fresh context. From the Java Docs:

> Test annotation which indicates that the ApplicationContext associated with a test is dirty and should therefore be closed and removed from the context cache.

> Use this annotation if a test has modified the context — for example, by modifying the state of a singleton bean, modifying the state of an embedded database, etc. Subsequent tests that request the same context will be supplied a new context.

> @DirtiesContext may be used as a class-level and method-level annotation within the same class or class hierarchy. In such scenarios, the ApplicationContext will be marked as dirty before or after any such annotated method as well as before or after the current test class, depending on the configured methodMode and classMode.

**Let me show you an example:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
public class SomeTestClass {

@Autowired
private ExampleController controller;

@Test
public void testSomething() {
   //Do some testing here
}
```

Now in this case, with an embedded DB (like H2), a fresh DB will be started containing no changes from previous transactions.

Please note that this will most probably slow down your test cases because creating a new context can be time consuming.

**Edit:**

If you watch the log output you'll see that Spring creates a new application context with everything included. So, when using an embedded DB for the test cases, Spring will drop the current DB and creates a new one and runs all specified migrations to it. It's like restarting the server which also creates a new embedded DB.

A new DB doesn't contain any commits from previous actions. That's why it works. It's actually not hacky imo but a proper set up for integration tests as integration tests mess up the DB and need the same clean setup. However, there are most probably other solutions as well because creating new contexts for every test class may slow down the execution time. So, I would recommend to annotate only classes (or methods) which really needs it. On the other hand, unit tests are in most cases not very time critical and with newer Spring versions lazy loading will speed up startup time.

Comment: i will try but I think this not solve my problem if inside transaction is another transaction which commited data, right?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter what you commit because you'll get a fresh application context, so it seems this is exactly what you're looking for

Comment: Yes, it looks that its working but I don't understand how it's possible :) Why doesn't matter what is commited? If data have been commited in Db application can't handle it anymore or can?

Comment: But we are using db with testcontainers so I am surprised that it works :)

Comment: Which DB are you using for the tests?

Comment: we are using PostgreSQL

Comment: It's because spring is actually dropping the whole database and recreating it again. So, there is indeed no need of an embedded DB per se if you use test containers with isolated environments